# Using an existing dataproc cluster to run dask

Tags: dask, google-cloud-dataproc, dask-distributed

I have a dataproc cluster running on the Google Cloud Platform. I intend to passing this cluster in the dask client instead of initializing a new dask-yarn cluster

However, I am not able to use my dataproc cluster directly

```
#Instead of :
cluster = YarnCluster(environment='environment.tar.gz',worker_vcores=2, worker_memory="8GiB")
cluster.scale(10)
client = Client(cluster)

#Directly using my dataproc cluster:
client = Client(my-dataproc-cluster)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataProc creates a new Hadoop cluster, `dask-yarn` is for creating dask clusters that run inside your hadoop cluster (wherever that may be). To run properly it requires properly setup python environments and configuration, just as any other tool on hadoop would (spark included).

We don't have a dataproc specific guide, but the one for AWS's equivalent EMR is here: http://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/aws-emr.html

For deploying on DataProc you'd likely create an equivalent [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) to the EMR bootstrap action: https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/blob/master/deployment_resources/aws-emr/bootstrap-dask

Comment: Do you have a dataproc guide at this time? Would love to try out Dask instead of Spark, but with limited documentation on getting things spun up, I might have to pass for now.

Comment: Dataproc now has an initialization action for Dask! https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/gcp-dataproc.html